# How can 'brand new, never before seen' IDs be counted per month in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

A fair amount of material is available detailing methods utilising `dense_rank()` and the like to count distinct somethings per month, however, I've been unable to find anything that allows a count of distinct per month which *also removes/discounts* any id's that have been seen in prior month groups.

The data can be imagined like so:

```
id (int8 type) | observed time (timestamp utc)
------------------
1  | 2017-01-01
2  | 2017-01-02
1  | 2017-01-02
1  | 2017-02-02
2  | 2017-02-03
3  | 2017-02-04
1  | 2017-03-01
3  | 2017-03-01
4  | 2017-03-01
5  | 2017-03-02
```

The process of the count can be seen as:

1: in 2017-01 we saw devices 1 and 2 so the count is 2

2: in 2017-02 we saw devices 1, 2 and 3. We know already about devices 1 and 2, but not 3, so the count is 1

3: in 2017-03 we saw devices 1, 3, 4 and 5. We already know about 1 and 3, but not 4 or 5, so the count is 2.

with the desired output being something like:

```
observed time | count of new id
--------------------------
2017-01       | 2
2017-02       | 1
2017-03       | 2
```

Explicitly, I am looking to have a new table, with an aggregated month per row, with a count of how many new ids occur within that month that have not been seen at all before.

The IRL case allows devices to be seen more than once in a month, but this shouldn't impact the count. It also uses integer for storage (both positive and negative) of the id, and time periods will be to the second in true timestamps. The size of the data set is also significant.

My initial attempt is along the lines of:

```
WITH records_months AS (
SELECT *,
date_trunc('month', observed_time) AS month_group
FROM my_table
WHERE observed_time > '2017-01-01')
id_months AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
month_group,
id
FROM records_months
GROUP BY month_group, id)
SELECT *
FROM id-months
```

However, I'm stuck on the next part i.e counting the number of new ID that were not seen in prior months. I believe the solution might be a window function, but I'm having trouble working out which or how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I thought of. The idea is to

- (innermost query) calculate the earliest month that each `id` was seen,
- (next level up) join that back to the main `my_table` dataset, and then
- (outer query) count distinct `id`s by month after nulling out the already-seen `id`s.

I tested it out and got the desired result set. Joining the earliest month back to the original table seemed like the most natural thing to do (vs. a window function). Hopefully this is performant enough for your Redshift!

```
select observed_month,
    -- Null out the id if the observed_month that we're grouping by
    -- is NOT the earliest month that the id was seen.
    -- Then count distinct id
    count(distinct(case when observed_month != earliest_month then null else id end)) as num_new_ids
from (
    select t.id,
        date_trunc('month', t.observed_time) as observed_month,
        earliest.earliest_month
    from my_table t
        join (
            -- What's the earliest month an id was seen?
            select id,
                date_trunc('month', min(observed_time)) as earliest_month
            from my_table
            group by 1
        ) earliest
        on t.id = earliest.id
)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe this to be correct. It's also fast enough for my requirements on our current IRL data set.